# How to insert math symbols in pseudocode in Markdown?

Tags: markdown

I want to use pseudocode in markdown. And there are some math symbols, can I insert math symbols in Markdown?

I know I can use the ```` ``` ```` to make a code block and choose a similar code language to show the pseudocode, but that can't show the math symbol . And I know how to use the math block, but the code can't be showed clearly.

Do you have some methods to use mathematical notation, primarily set notation, in a code block?

Comment: What do you mean by "fake code"? Are there specific mathematical symbols that you want to use?

Comment: Yes, I  mean use "fake code". Mathematical symbols like some set operations.

Comment: ...when somebody asks you "what do you mean by 'x'", answering "I mean 'x'" usually isn't helpful. What's "fake" about this code?

Comment: sorry, I mean pseudocode in fact. The translator mistakes me.

Comment: @fish-404 If you mean something like MathJax that's not supported here on SO, even though it is on other sites like [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best bet is probably to use [Unicode](http://www.unicode.org/charts/) characters, e.g.

```
for { x ∈ ℤ | 10 ≤ x < 20 } do
   ...
end
```

or

```
Z = X ∩ Y
```

You can copy and paste them from the web, or use something like a [compose key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compose_key) or a [Windows Alt code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alt_code). The [mathematical operators range](https://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2200.pdf) is likely a good place to start.

Comment: Another good place to find many math symbols to copy is the [MathJax cheatsheet](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

I'm facing with this problem right now, I'm trying to build a README.md on GitHub with pseudocode which has math formulas/symbols. I found a solution working with nested blockquotes, as follows:

```
>while not convergence:
>
>> compute $\nabla(J)$
>>
>> $\theta_0 := \theta_0 - \alpha\nabla(J)_0$
>>
>> $\theta_1 := \theta_1 - \alpha\nabla(J)_1$
>
>end while
```

[image: Screenshot of GitHub's rendering README.md]

Comment: Great Solution! Take tests in different parsers. Seems GitHub Flavored Markdown and GitLab Flavored Markdown can support this feature in their preview, even I don't see similar example in their user guide(and sometimes the `>>` can't be parsed in GitHub preview, may try multiple times). Editors like MarkText used GFM can also support this. Commen Markdown seems can't support this. (By the way, your screenshot seems can't be reached, it returns error "Imgur is temporarily over capacity.)

Comment: A disadvantage is using blockquotes we can't have syntax highlight.